# OpenGL Compute Shader Wont Compile If Includes Input Image

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpgpu, compute-shader

This GLSL source code compiles (using GL_COMPUTE_SHADER) and runs with no issue (only uses output image):

```
#version 460
layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;
layout (rgba8, binding = 3) uniform writeonly lowp image2D destTex;
void main() {
  ivec2 pixel_coords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
  imageStore(destTex, pixel_coords, vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)); // Solid red
}
```

But if I add only two lines of code to allow for an input image, the following doesn't compile:

```
#version 460
layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;
layout (rgba8, binding = 1) uniform readonly lowp image2D srcTex;
layout (rgba8, binding = 3) uniform writeonly lowp image2D destTex;
void main() {
  ivec2 pixel_coords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
  vec4 color = imageLoad(srcTex​, pixel_coords);
  imageStore(destTex, pixel_coords, color);
}
```

The output of the compiler is:

```
0(7) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting "::" at token "<undefined>"
0(8) : error C1503: undefined variable "color"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) character (which is invisible) between the 'x' and the comma in `imageLoad`. After erasing it, your code compiled fine for me.

Comment: That was it. How could you tell from the error message?

Comment: @Labeno I didn't. I copied and pasted the code and got the error (from glslangValidator) `ERROR: 0:7: '�' : unexpected token`. So I used `hexdump` to find where the character was, then just pasted the character into the Python interpreter and googled the code.